# Git remove new untracked files

Tags: git, git-branch

this should be simple but i cant find the right anwer 
I am new to git I added a bunch of new files (not staged) to my git tree i want to just delete them without also deleting the git ignore files in that directory any commands? the

```
git clean -nd
```

command tells me it will erase all my .git ignore files as well?

Comment: User interactive approach : git clean -i -fd

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For your case, you could give an exclude parameter:

```
git clean -nd -e **/.gitignore
```

---

However, normally, I think it would be recommended to do either of these instead:

- Commit your `.gitignore` file. If the ignore rules are useful for everyone who uses the repo, then it makes sense to push it to the remote. `git clean` will not remove committed files.
- If you have personal ignore rules, put them in the `.git/info/exclude` file instead of a `.gitignore` file. (This is a recommendation from [gitignore documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore))

Answer (score 6):

Use -f parameter:

```
git clean -f
```

Comment: I want it to remove entire directorys that command only removes files

Comment: also that command erases my .gitignore files which I wrote in my question i dont want to do that

Comment: `git clean -f` does *not* remove files listed inside `.gitignore`. If it does on your repository, it means that the `.gitignore` file has not been added and committed to the repository.

Comment: To remove directories, run `git clean -f -d` or `git clean -fd`